# Set a max volume for the Terminal bell

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, gnome-terminal, volume-control, terminal-bell

Is there a way to set the max volume the terminal bell can be? That us say it is at volume x when system volume is at 50%, when I go over 50% I want the bell sound to stay at x volume. There does not appear to be a way to set it from Pulseaudio control. I do not want to turn the bell off.

I ask this for the sake of my ears when I use headphones. Some web pages will be at comfortable volume at 100% system volume but the terminal is painful at this level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the system alerts sound level by this way:

1. Go to the "gear cog" in the upper right corner of the screen.
2. Select **System settings...**
3. Click on **Sound**.
4. Click on the **Sound Effects** tab.
5. Lower the **Alert volume** to a comfortable level (or mute it).

Here you're a screenshot:

[image: Sound settings]

Comment: Ok. I was looking for a setting in pulseaudio volume... Makes sense that it would be in the standard sound menu.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, it's Settings > Sound > Volume Levels > System Sounds.

Answer (score 1):

The following prevents the readline(3) program used by bash(1) to beep when encountering an alert character (ASCII=7).

> $ echo "set bell-style none">> ~/.inputrc