# How to adjust the volume of the alert sound in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, gnome-terminal, volume-control

How can I lower (or increase) the volume of the alert sound *only*, while leaving other sound volumes at the current level?

Older versions of Ubuntu had allowed the user to explicitly control the volume of the alert sound (see [Set a max volume for the Terminal bell](https://askubuntu.com/a/607554/100356)) but I do not see this capability in newer Ubuntu releases.